# Json Error With [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, displayformat

I Write a mvc5 project in vs2013

A method in controller returns json

```
public JsonResult QueryConcens(ConcentratorView concenForQuery)
{
    QueryConcentratorsRequest request = new QueryConcentratorsRequest() { ConcenQuery = concenForQuery };

    return
        Json
        (
            concenstratorService
            .QueryConcentrators(request)
            .ConcensView
        );
}
```

the model is

```
public class ConcentratorView
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="please input id")]
    public string ConcentratorID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

it returns:

```
[{"ConcentratorID":"43","Name":"345","Address":"345"},
{"ConcentratorID":"56","Name":"","Address":null},
{"ConcentratorID":"concen_123","Name":"wer","Address":null}]
```

I want the Address:null to be ""

then I Add

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

but it returns

```
[{"ConcentratorID":"43","Name":"345","Address":"345"}]
```

it losts two rows

Why?